# How to display chapter/section counter value?

Tags: counters

I'm building a `\documentclass[...]{book}` latex file. Each chapter has some sections. Each section has some exercises. The exercises are displayed on `\exercise` command. In the preamble I did:

```
\newcommand{\exercise}{
    \paragraph{Exercício x}
}
```

How can I set `x = \chapter . \section . \mycounter`?

The `\mycounter` counter has to reset at beginning of each new section (I don't care about chapter because all exercises will be inside a section).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\thechapter.\thesection.\themycounter`? or better define `\themycounter` as `\renecommand{\thechapter.\thesection.\arabic{mycounter}}` . welcome to tex.se!

Comment: @Zarko Under normal circumstances `\thesection` already prints the chapter number, so `\thechapter.\thesection` would duplicate the chapter number.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, well, you explain this in your answer. but not knowing anything about op document, it is difficult to say what is usual ... :-).

Comment: @Zarko I completely agree :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a counter `exercise` with `\newcounter{exercise}`, then you say that it restarts at every section with `\counterwithin{exercise}{section}`.

To make `\thesection` (which prints the value of the section) to be `chapter.section.exercise` you can use `\thesection.\arabic{exercise}` because `\thesection` is already defined to print `chapter.section`. Of course you could also use `\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{exercise}`, but then if any of them happened to be, for instance, with roman numbers, it would look inconsistent.

Finally, at each exercise you use `\refstepcounter{exercise}` to add one to it, and print `\theexercise`.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{exercise}
\counterwithin{exercise}{section}
\renewcommand\theexercise{%
  \thesection.\arabic{exercise}%
}
\newcommand{\exercise}{%
  \refstepcounter{exercise}%
  \paragraph{Exercício~\theexercise}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{I don't care about}

\section{This section}

\exercise \lipsum[1]

\exercise \lipsum[2]

\section{Another section}

\exercise \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```